# unknown real-time background manipulation on e-commerce shop

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing

I stumbled upon a German ecommerce site that seems to manipulate via filter all product images' background on the fly and I need to know how that works.

Original URL with exmaplary product image:
https://toom.de/p/kapp-gehrungssaege-hm80l/1500896

If I inspect it this url with some variables is given and obviously the "more or less" white background of product image is changed to a consistent #f5f5f5 gray tone.

https://static.toom.de/produkte/bilder/aktionsartikel/1500896.png?quality=85&bg-color=f5f5f5&width=960&grey=1&format=jpg

I need to know how this is working.

I always have problems to make nice product photography with consistent white background (255 255 255 / #fff). So, I think this way of manipulating background via filter could be very handy.
I asked the good programmers I know about this and showed them the toom.de website but no could tell me how they made that....

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css filter property if you are not going with service what they using , but you need to manually set the percent to fit in to your background.

```
img{
  filter: invert(4%);
}
```

if you want to know just inspect their content where they use image and use following code.

HTML

```
<img class="a-picture__image" data-js-picture-image="" src="https://static.toom.de/produkte/bilder/aktionsartikel/1500896.png" srcset="https://static.toom.de/produkte/bilder/aktionsartikel/1500896.png" alt="hauptbild">
```

Css

```
.a-picture__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    filter: invert(4%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They have written an service to change image based on query string what you provide with image source based on that they return back the image as response .

For example check i have changed the query string for width you will get to see the differences.

Original what you given : https://static.toom.de/produkte/bilder/aktionsartikel/1500896.png?quality=85&bg-color=f5f5f5&width=960&grey=1&format=jpg

and i changed query string `width:160`: https://static.toom.de/produkte/bilder/aktionsartikel/1500896.png?quality=85&bg-color=f5f5f5&width=160&grey=1&format=jpg

check the differences